# May I have a simple Suitelet example?

Tags: netsuite

I am reading through the Suitescript 2.0 manual just trying to understand the manual itself let alone Suitescript. Can someone provide a simple example how a suitelet would display out to an html page? Like a simple recordtype record field value to display out to a web page. Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here is a basic "Hello World!" Suitelet in SS2.0

```
/**
 *@NApiVersion 2.x
 *@NScriptType Suitelet
 *@NModuleScope SameAccount
 */

define([], function() {
  function onRequest(params) {
    var html = '<h1>Hello World!<h1>';
    params.response.write({ output: html });
  }

  return {
    onRequest: onRequest
  };
});
```

Comment: This is perfect, I have a stupid question. How would this look in the html. I think that is where my disconnect is.

Comment: @TragicWhale I am not sure what you mean. You can output whatever HTML you want by modifying the `html` var in the example.

Comment: I know, I feel like I am asking what 1+1 is at this point, kind of embarassing but what I am asking is where is the script ran to actually display a webpage? Is it in another html file, who or what calls this script. Thanks in advanced for your help.

Comment: @TragicWhale Oh I think I understand what you mean. What you would do is save this file to your File Cabinet, and then create a) A new Script Record, b) a Script Deployment Record. On the Script Deployment, you will be able to see the URL to run the Suitelet.

Comment: Ah ok, hm, mine returned an error a module not existing. Ill figure that out. I'll keep working at it from there but you've help tremendously on this Everest of learning an api. Ha. Thanks Michoel.

Comment: Error module not existing is solved by adding a .js at the end of your script filename.

Answer (score 2):

I have some examples that can help you get started on some popular Suitescript 2.0 types including Suitelets at [ursuscode.com](https://ursuscode.com/netsuite-tips/suitescript-2-0-quickstart-samples/). Check them out.

Comment: Hey Adolfo, can you tell me how the scripts are implemented on a html file?

Comment: I don't understand your question. Could you elaborate more?

Comment: Ofcourse, so I used the simple script of hello world. I added it to the cabinet and it runs perfectly when clicking the external or internal link for the script in netsuite. My question is, can I run the hello world script within a portion of an html page so as to show Hello World in addition to another part of a page, ie:
Top of page //Text on first line of page
Hello World //Text pulled from script

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Yeah, you could do several things. For instance you can create an iFrame within your HTML and have that iFrame load the Suitelet contents. You can also use javascript in your HTML to do an AJAX call to the Suitelet and then do something with the response such as modify the contents of a div. Basically you can use your Suitelet as a Node JS server.

Comment: Adolfo, this is excellent advice. I really dont know how to do it but now that you have given me good direction I can figure it out. Thanks so much.

Answer (score 0):

```
/**
*@NApiVersion 2.x
*@NScriptType Suitelet
*/

define([],function() { // NetSuite's AMD pattern
    function onRequest_entry(context) { // Suitelet entry function receives a context obj
        context.response.write('Hello World'); // Write a response using the context obj
    }
    return {
        onRequest: onRequest_entry // Function assigned to entry point
    };
});
```